# xCode install help

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i set up xcode to **install** about 4 hours ago from the appstore. It has been at about 1 millimeter from complete for the past half+ hour and it is not frozen. Is this normal?

i am using an old mac book pro.

**Answer**:

force quit xcode installer once it starts to hang and then it works. Maybe apple forgot how to calculate when it is 100% done correctly? lol

I found the answer on the link David provided. I posted this edit so it is clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a common problem and has been previously reported to Apple.  Run Software Update and restart your machine.  You have to update iTunes for the sync services.

Start App Store again, and go to the purchased tab to re-download it.

https://discussions.apple.com/message/13205586?messageID=13205586

You can also try pausing for a minute, then unpausing before trying the above.

Comment: there is no option to pause the install. there is only a quit option that is disabled

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't make it clear - is it the *download* that's nearly complete, or the *install*? If it's the download, you may have had a hiccup with your internet connection. It happens - especially if you use Comcast, grumble grumble... If that's the case, then just pause, wait a second, then restart the download.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but I had similar problems installing XCode on Snow Leopard.  I had to uninstall the old version of XCode then install from scratch.

There are these install tips: http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1394. There might also be a way to run the installation from the command prompt and log errors.

Comment: This is the first time I'm installing it though